# have truncate and drop index better performance than drop table, create tale and create index?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a simple question:

Scenario:

Whose Perfomance is better ?

1)

```
DROP INDEX -->
TRUNCATE TABLE --> 
AND THEN FILLUP DATA -->
AND THEN CREATE INDEX
```

2)

```
DROP TABLE -->
CREATE TABLE -->
FILLUP DATA-->
CREATE INDEX
```

I am using a table with millinos of recods.  Which of these queries would suit my needs best?

Comment: And what exactly are your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between the two methods, populating the data and then creating the index will be 99% of the time it takes to do the operation, I wouldn't worry that much if truncate or drop is faster after all both are not fully logged operations

Comment: Both creating an index and filling data is done on each case.  So it really doesn't matter.

Comment: That is what I am saying also

Comment: if i had to do this 1400 times in a loop, then which will perform better?
Or another track shld i look for?

My scenario is :
i have to take data from One billion records table and create 10-12 tables from this table based on criteria from another tables too.
then left join these tables to other tables & finally output in another tables.
Please tell me if i fetch 0.7 milions of records in a loop it takes 72 hours. how can i reduce the time?

Comment: like I said the drop or truncate statement will not use up any significant time compared to the other operations like insert and index creation

Comment: If i say that --> 
step 1 )Drop the table
Step 2) Create table 
Step 3) Create Index 
will be better as in this case Indexes will not be fragmented pls tell me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The only real answer here is to try it and see - I expect that there will be very little difference in performance.